# How to make a C# loop interactive

Tags: c#, winforms

I am uploading files to an FTP folder using C# WinForms

but while the form is uploading files the whole form freezes.

I would like the user to click cancel button or add more files or do anything else.

how can I do that?

here is my code

```
                foreach (ListViewItem item in lvwFiles.Items)
                {
                    string fileName = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                    string uploadFile = item.SubItems[1].Text;

                    try
                    {
                        txtLog.Text = fileName + " uploading..." + "\n\r\n\r" + txtLog.Text;
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadFile, FileMode.Open))
                        {

                            client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass Payload error large files
                            client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadFile));
                        }

                         
                        txtLog.Text = fileName + " has been uploaded successfully." + "\n\r\n\r" + txtLog.Text;
                        item.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 128);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        txtLog.Text = fileName + " error: " + ex.ToString() + "\n\r\n\r" + txtLog.Text;
                        item.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Static `HttpClient` + `List<Task>` + `CancellationTokenSource` + `Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: @Jimi i do not get it

Comment: Declare a `static` HttpClient object (or `static Lazy<HttpClient>`, probably better here), create an async method that accepts a CancellationToken (using a single CancellationTokenSource, if you want to cancel all downloads) which downloads a file (this method returns a `Task<Something>`), create a `List<Task>` to hold as many tasks as the number of files to download, add all Tasks to the List, await `Task.WhenAll([Your List of Tasks])` to wait asynchronously for the downloads to complete. -- An `IProgress<T>` delegate can be used to report the progress of the operations(s)...

Comment: If you plan on having many concurrent downloads, your async method may return the path of the file it downloaded (or fail if it could not complete) instead of a byte array.